# What is a good replacement for MyGeneration / d00dads code generation and data layer?

Tags: c#, .net, mygeneration

I have used MyGeneration and the d00dads architecture for several years, and have been a big proponent.  The tool is fairly simple and straightforward and the code layer is dead simple.
But a recent experience with it has left me a bit wary now.  Support for this software is completely non-existent, any forums dealing with it are virtual ghost towns.  I am scared of running into another issue later down the road that I cannot fix and being stuck.

I'm looking for something that:

Explicitly supports MS SQL Server and C#.

Simple: No XML schemas!  Straighforward tools.  Just convert SQL tables to easily accessible objects and collections

Supported: Developer support is essential.  A robust forum community with ongoing bug fixes is ideal.

A year or two ago I would have agreed with the answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975/can-you-recommend-a-good-free-code-generator).  Hell, I may have even upvoted that answer.  But I just can't justify that anymore.  It's dead software and the source code is complicated enough it's not something you can just dive in and update without prior experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Microsoft's Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx)?

LINQ to SQL is probably a little simpler, but it's been "officially" replaced by the EF.

** UPDATE **

Here's the 3.5 EF [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Says .NET 4.0 is a requirement... I'm running 3.5 on production servers right now and can't upgrade yet.  :|  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: That's not true, the particular link I posted was for the .net 4.0 version of the EF, but there is a 3.5 version as well.

Comment: Updated this to be the correct answer.  Should have happened earlier!  EF still very well supported.  Lots of documentation, getting started guides, and community support.

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at [CodeSmith Generator's](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator) [Framework templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/frameworks)? I'd recommend taking a look at [.NetTiers](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/frameworks#nettiers) as it would be a good replacement for d00dads. Other developers have went this route. Otherwise we have the [PLINQO templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/frameworks#plinqo) and soon to be [PLINQO for Enity Framework](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/frameworks#plinqoef).

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski ([CodeSmith Employee](http://www.codesmithtools.com/))

Comment: What did you end up choosing as a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's uncouth to answer one's own question, but...  after digging into this a bit, the answer became pretty obvious: [Entity Spaces](http://www.entityspaces.net/Portal/Default.aspx) is the logical replacement for MyGeneration/dOOdads.  Written by the same person, uses a similar syntax and design patterns.  Only con is that it is not a free tool.

Comment: Yep this one is defunct as well.  I should un-check my answer.  Sticking with Entity Framework for now, MS seems to be supporting it well.  I don't think it's going to go away anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is a very old post, but it still ranks pretty high on DuckDuckGo results.

The MyGeneration guy has created https://www.My2ndGeneration.com.  It's not syntax compatible with the first, but it's still pretty nice.

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know. Although I'd be a little wary of diving into one of his projects after he abandoned the first two. How long will this one last?

Comment: I couldn't find any forum support for my2ndgeneration and I couldn't find how to do something as simple as to load a SQL Server table to generate code from.